# Loop through commit messages in Github Workflow

Tags: maven, github, devops, workflow

I am trying to automatize java maven project versioning regarding commit messages. (starting from recent merge)

if a developer pushes -m "taskNumber [major]"
github workflow needs to read that message and run

```
$ mvn validate -DbumpMajor
```

```
$ mvn validate -DbumpMinor
```

```
$ mvn validate -DbumpPatch
```

and so on

However, when I try to read commit messages, it is always empty/null

here is the workflow yml code

```
commits=${{join(github.event.commits.message, ', ') }}  
echo $commits
echo 'end of commit message'
```

this piece of code was in Github community but I am not sure Github supports it now.

Any insight?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what kind of Maven commands these are: `$ mvn bump major
`... Why does the github workflow needs to read the commit message? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, thanks for your comment. as I mentioned in the 1st paragraph of the question, "I am trying to automatize java maven project versioning regarding commit messages."  this is the accomplishment.  maven commands which I am trying, are custom profiles which increase the pom version files. i edited commands